# Am I properly opening and reading files into Pandas ?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I am trying to open a folder in a file path and wanting to read all the files data into dataframes, but not sure if I am doing it properly or are there much simpler ways?

In the code you will see after line 32 I am calling in a access file to populate the dataframe with the column names in it, but this is failing if anyone could show me this that would be great, but main objective is am I pulling the files properly?

Code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc


loc = 'D:/filepath'
os.chdir(loc)
filelist = os.listdir()
#print (len((pd.concat([pd.read_csv(item, names=[item[:-4]]) for item in filelist],axis=1))))

def Read_Data(input_file):
    try:
        print("Processing: " + str(input_file))
        Read = "pd.read_table('" + input_file + "',error_bad_lines  = False, warn_bad_lines = True,encoding='cp037')"
        print(Read)        
        df=eval(Read)
        output_df = input_file[:-4]+"_df"
        print(output_df)
        eval(output_df+ "= df")
    except:
        print("Problem in " + str(input_file))

[Read_Data(file) for file in filelist]


pypyodbc.lowercase = False
conn = pypyodbc.connect(
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
    r"Dbq=D:filepath;")
cur = conn.cursor
cur.execute("SELECT ACCOUNT,RELATIONSHIP_TYPE FROM owners"  );
while True:
    row = cur.fetchone
    if row is None:
        break
    print(u"ACCOUNT with ID {0}".format(
        row.get("ACCOUNT"), row.get("RELATIONSHIP_TYPE")))

cur.close
conn.close()
```